# How to make string from multidimential array values using parent child values ? - Dynamic SQL query generator

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, multidimensional-array

this is dynamic array data. i have mention below sample data from this i need to generate **SQL** query

Im using VueJs + Laravel. below i updated array data and methods

```
[
  {
    "operator": "AND",
    "rules": [
      {
        "id": 100,
        "column": "dd_Tttp",
        "type": "equal",
        "value": true,

        "join": "AND",
      }
    ],
    "groups": [
      {
        "operator": "AND",
        "rules": [
          {
            "id": 200,
            "column": "dd_tering",
            "type": "equal",
            "value": true,

            "join": "AND",

          },
          {
            "id": 201,
            "column": "dd_Size",
            "type": "in",
            "value": "Standard",

            "join": "AND",

          },
          {
            "id": 202,
            "column": "dd_Lotpth",
            "type": "equal",
            "value": "12",

            "join": "AND",

          }
        ],
        "groups": [
          {
            "operator": "AND",
            "rules": [

              {
                "id": 300,
                "column": "dd_cat",
                "type": "equal",
                "value": "34",

                "join": "AND",

              },
              {
                "id": 301,
                "column": "dd_Cot",
                "type": "in",
                "value": "Coftlassic",

                "join": "AND",

              },
              {
                "id": 302,
                "column": "dd_dse",
                "type": "equal",
                "value": "2020-01-01",

                "join": "AND",

              },
              {
                "id": 303,
                "column": "dd_turflaid",
                "type": "equal",
                "value": true,

                "join": "AND",

              }
            ],
            "groups": [

            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "operator": "AND",
    "rules": [

      {
        "id": 100,
        "column": "dd_get",
        "type": "equal",
        "value": true,

        "join": "AND",
      },
      {
        "id": 101,
        "column": "dd_ccc",
        "type": "in",
        "value": "Standard",

        "join": "AND",
      }
    ],
    "groups": [

    ]
  }
]
```

passing above array data to this function i want get out put like this

```
(dd_Tttp = 'true' (dd_tering = 'true' AND dd_Size IN ('Standard') AND dd_Lotpth = '12' AND (dd_cat = '34' AND dd_Cot IN ('Coftlassic') AND dd_dse = '2020-01-01' AND dd_turflaid = 'true'))) AND (dd_get = 'true' AND dd_ccc IN ('Standard'))



groupQueryGen(groups){

   let self = this;
   let join = ''; 
   let gggg = '';

  $.each(groups, function(key, group) {

        gggg = self.groupQueryGen(group.groups);
       //console.log('group',gggg);
       join = self.ruleQueryGen(group.rules);


       join += join + '( '+gggg+' )';
    });


    return join ;

}

ruleQueryGen(rules){
    let join = '';
    $.each(rules, function(index, value) {
        if(value)
        {
            if(value.type == 'equal'){
                join += value.colum+" = '"+ value.value+"' "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'not_equal'){
                join += value.colum+" != '"+ value.value+"' "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'in'){
                join += value.colum+" IN ('"+ value.value+"') "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'not_in'){
                join += value.colum+" NOT IN ('"+ value.value+"') "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'less'){
                join += value.colum+" < '"+ value.value+"' "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'less_or_equal'){
                join += value.colum+" <= '"+ value.value+"' "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'greater'){
                join += value.colum+" > '"+ value.value+"' "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'greater_or_equal'){
                join += value.colum+" >= '"+ value.value+"' "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'between'){
                join += value.colum+" BETWEEN '"+ value.value+"' AND '" + value.valueTwo+ "' "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'not_between'){
                join += " NOT ("+value.colum+" BETWEEN '"+ value.value+"' AND '" + value.valueTwo+"') "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'is_null'){
                join += value.colum+" IS NULL "+value.join+" ";
            }else if(value.type == 'is_not_null'){
                join += value.colum+" IS NOT NULL "+value.join+" ";
            }

        }

    });

    return join;

}
```

Comment: What is the role of `.operator`? You seem to use `.join` instead for the same purpose? `.join` seems to make less sense, as logically for 5 rules, you need 4 joins, not 5... Also, if you are just going to append the join type, what is the use of the recursive structure? I would work with `.operator` and drop `.join` completely.

Comment: I feel that `groups` should appear *inside* a `rule`. I find your structure quite confusing.

Comment: Is this structure a *must*, or can we suggest a different one?

Comment: yes you can restructure array @trincot but `join` and `operator` both need to make perfect query

Comment: @trincot in final data you won't get first and last group `operator` and in rules first and last `join`

Comment: I don't see how there is anything you need both for. You can make a structure without one of the two to express any ruleset

Comment: Please add in your question the final sql you expect without `...`

Comment: @trincot `join` for between two rules and `operator` between two gropus example `(rule JOIN  rule JOIN rule ) OPERATOR (rule JOIN  rule JOIN rule) OPERATOR (rule JOIN  rule JOIN rule) OPERATOR (rule JOIN  rule JOIN rule)`

Comment: Not needed to have two different props for that. A recursive group can take care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a different structure, because:

- There is no need to make the distinction between `operator` and `join`.
- `groups` and `rules` should really be the same concept. When it should have nested rules, then just use a nested `rules` property.
- When you use the types `in` or `between`, the `value` property should really be an array. The parser should inject the commas and other SQL syntax. Don't put commas inside a single string (although you don't have such examples)
- Avoid parsing `not_between` and `not_is_null` separately; they are just the same thing as `between` and `is_null`, but with a `NOT` applied to it. That can be done more dynamically.

Here is the suggested structure for your example:

```
{
    "type": "AND",
    "rules": [{
        "id": 100,
        "column": "dd_Tttp",
        "type": "equal",
        "value": true
    }, {
        "type": "AND",
        "rules": [{
            "id": 200,
            "column": "dd_tering",
            "type": "equal",
            "value": true
        }, {
            "id": 201,
            "column": "dd_Size",
            "type": "in",
            "value": ["Standard"] // You should use arrays for type="in"
        }, {
            "id": 202,
            "column": "dd_Lotpth",
            "type": "equal",
            "value": "12"
        }, {
            "type": "AND",
            "rules": [{
                "id": 300,
                "column": "dd_cat",
                "type": "equal",
                "value": "34"
            }, {
                "id": 301,
                "column": "dd_Cot",
                "type": "in",
                "value": ["Coftlassic"]  // You should use arrays for type="in"
            }, {
                "id": 302,
                "column": "dd_dse",
                "type": "equal",
                "value": "2020-01-01"
            }, {
                "id": 303,
                "column": "dd_turflaid",
                "type": "equal",
                "value": true
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "AND",
        "rules": [{
            "id": 100,
            "column": "dd_get",
            "type": "equal",
            "value": true
        }, {
            "id": 101,
            "column": "dd_ccc",
            "type": "in",
            "value": ["Standard"] //  // You should use arrays for type="in"
        }]
    }]
};
```

Here is a snippet that produces the SQL from that:

```js
const op = { equal: " = ", not_equal: " <> ", less: " < ", less_or_equal: " <= ",
             greater: " > ", greater_or_equal: " >= " };

function toSql(rule) {
     // recursive case:
    if (rule.rules) return "(" + rule.rules.map(toSql).join("\n" + rule.type + "  ") + ")";
    // Base case (it is an atomic rule):
    if (op[rule.type]) return rule.column + op[rule.type] + JSON.stringify(rule.value); 
    // Deal with "not": that is just a negation of the opposite
    let type = rule.type.replace(/^not_/, ""); 
    let sql = rule.column + (
           type === "in" ? " IN (" + JSON.stringify(rule.value).slice(1,-1) + ")"
         : type === "between" ? " BETWEEN " + rule.value.map(item => JSON.stringify(item)).join(" AND ") 
         : type === "is_null" ? " IS NULL"
         : "<UNKNOWN TYPE:" + type + ">"
    );
    return type === rule.type ? sql : "NOT (" + sql + ")";
}

let rule = {"type": "AND","rules": [{"id": 100,"column": "dd_Tttp","type": "equal","value": true}, {"type": "AND","rules": [{"id": 200,"column": "dd_tering","type": "equal","value": true}, {"id": 201,"column": "dd_Size","type": "in","value": ["Standard"]}, {"id": 202,"column": "dd_Lotpth","type": "equal","value": "12"}, {"type": "AND","rules": [{"id": 300,"column": "dd_cat","type": "equal","value": "34"}, {"id": 301,"column": "dd_Cot","type": "in","value": ["Coftlassic"]}, {"id": 302,"column": "dd_dse","type": "equal","value": "2020-01-01"}, {"id": 303,"column": "dd_turflaid","type": "equal","value": true}]}]}, {"type": "AND","rules": [{"id": 100,"column": "dd_get","type": "equal","value": true}, {"id": 101,"column": "dd_ccc","type": "in","value": ["Standard"]}]}]};

console.log(toSql(rule));
```

#### Disabling rules

In comments you add a requirement where you want to have some rules disabled. In that case, first filter the rules by a new property `disabled`.

Here is the same snippet with that change, and where the final two (nested) rules are disabled:

```js
const op = { equal: " = ", not_equal: " <> ", less: " < ", less_or_equal: " <= ",
             greater: " > ", greater_or_equal: " >= " };

function toSql(rule) {
     // recursive case:
    if (rule.rules) {
        // Filter out recursive return values that are empty (using Boolean):
        let sql = rule.rules.map(toSql).filter(Boolean).join("\n" + rule.type + "  ");
        // return that SQL in parentheses, except when it is empty
        return sql ? "(" + sql + ")" : "";
    }
    // Base case (it is an atomic rule):
    if (rule.disabled) return ""; // Return empty string when disabled
    if (op[rule.type]) return rule.column + op[rule.type] + JSON.stringify(rule.value);
    // Deal with "not": that is just a negation of the opposite
    let type = rule.type.replace(/^not_/, ""); 
    let sql = rule.column + (
           type === "in" ? " IN (" + JSON.stringify(rule.value).slice(1,-1) + ")"
         : type === "between" ? " BETWEEN " + rule.value.map(item => JSON.stringify(item)).join(" AND ") 
         : type === "is_null" ? " IS NULL"
         : "<UNKNOWN TYPE:" + type + ">"
    );
    return type === rule.type ? sql : "NOT (" + sql + ")";
}

let rule = {"type": "AND","rules": [{"id": 100,"column": "dd_Tttp","type": "equal","value": true}, {"type": "AND","rules": [{"id": 200,"column": "dd_tering","type": "equal","value": true}, {"id": 201,"column": "dd_Size","type": "in","value": ["Standard"]}, {"id": 202,"column": "dd_Lotpth","type": "equal","value": "12"}, {"type": "AND","rules": [{"id": 300,"column": "dd_cat","type": "equal","value": "34"}, {"id": 301,"column": "dd_Cot","type": "in","value": ["Coftlassic"]}, {"id": 302,"column": "dd_dse","type": "equal","value": "2020-01-01"}, {"id": 303,"column": "dd_turflaid","type": "equal","value": true}]}]}, {"type": "AND","rules": [{"id": 100,disabled:true,"column": "dd_get","type": "equal","value": true}, {"id": 101,disabled:true,"column": "dd_ccc","type": "in","value": ["Standard"]}]}]};

console.log(toSql(rule));
```

Comment: ignoring `join` doesn't give proper output what i need. i change one type as OR but its changing 3 places. but i want one place OR condition here ? how can i put ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S-nrrQu7D_b68AGGcWtvpnX91XVA2HqR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you make it on PHP with my structure ?

Comment: If you want an OR between two expressions only, you must surround those two expressions in a separate rule. Please don't post images. I took the example of your question. If you have another example output, that you think this code cannot make, then please edit your question and add that example. I assure you that *every* possible combination of AND and OR, whereever you want it, can be expressed this way. I will not use your structure for the reasons I explained in my answer. It is not a good structure in my opinion.

Comment: thanks and i have mention first line of my question its dynamic data. so all the values can  be change including join

Comment: Of course. Do you have an example SQL which you feel cannot be achieved with my suggested solution?

Comment: don't u think we don't get any requirement `(condition1 AND cond2 OR cond3)` ike this ?? anyway i changed my data structure and removed **join**

Comment: `(condition1 AND cond2 OR cond3)` could be ambiguous, unless we agree that `AND` has precedence over `OR`. Any way, it would be good practice to be explicit about the precedence and use extra paretheses:  `( (condition1 AND cond2) OR cond3)` or `(condition1 AND (cond2 OR cond3) )` . Both can be represented in the proposed data structure.

Comment: is there any way to use condition to join ?  example each rule has status key so if status key true only it will comping with query otherwise ignore 
i tried but im getting unwanted AND or OR check image and give me idea - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lvLCBUW92gK2D17PCpzbfJqXG05FL0vy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Change `rule.rules.map(toSql)` to `rule.rules.filter(rule => !rule.disabled).map(toSql)` and make sure you have `disabled: true` in your data structure for any rule you want to omit.

Comment: if last rule `disabled:true` then im getting ex `WHERE (tran_accpacitemvendor != '44rrr'
AND  ())` how to avoid this

Comment: The comment section is not really intended for follow-up questions, but OK, I have extended my answer with this requirement. It is slightly different from what I suggested in my previous comment.